# Binance api key and secret queryString malformed

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, get, api-key

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to get info of my account but something is not correct.

```
var apiKey = 'myAPIKey';
var secret = 'mySecret';
var queryString = 'timestamp=' + Date.now();
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(queryString,secret);
var url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?'+ queryString + '&signature=' +hash;

$('.botonOrden').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(req){
            req.setRequestHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", apiKey);
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: url
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

The console says:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1522383455036&signature=***MyHash***.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I'm think I'm doing it as shown in the doc:
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv1order

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#account-information-user_data

Comment: I don't get Cross-Origin Request Blocked error, i get 404 error:https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/mxxRro

Comment: you need to open a binance account and put your apiKey and Secret in the variables var apiKey; and var secret; and then it send a GET request with correct url

Comment: even that it shouldn't get 404 error, it should show invalid key error.try with invalid key and see what you get

Comment: you right, my mistake, actually I update the code to make me understand better:

Comment: $('.botonOrden').click(function(){
 var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time';
 callOtherDomain();
 function callOtherDomain(){
   if(invocation)
     {
       invocation.open('GET', url, true);
       invocation.send(); 
     }
}
});

Comment: now with this code the server just return the actual server time no needed keys, I have a 200 response but not returned the JSON, but if you write the URL in your browser you will get the JSON, try it and see

Comment: i did few research and it's a problem with chrome, either you have to use Firefox or use this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

Comment: tks, also I found this:  https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/  it help a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered 400 errors with the same 'account' API call as you did.

The solution I found was to request a timestamp from the Binance server (using /api/v1/time) and not generate it myself.

Secondly I had to add **&recvWindow=5000** to the query string next to the timestamp.

The recvWindow is in the Binance documentation an optional parameter, but I learned the hard way that what is written is not always true… The recVWindow made it work.

I hope this helps resolving the issue.